# How to edit the size of the submit button on a form?

Tags: html, css, forms

Hi I don't want an image for my submit button so I have gone with the default submit button but I want to edit its width and height. How do I do that?

```
<input type="submit" id="search" value="Search"  />
```

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Using CSS you can set a style for that specific button using the id (#) selector:

```css
#search {
    width: 20em;  height: 2em;
}
```

or if you want all submit buttons to be a particular size:

```css
input[type=submit] {
    width: 20em;  height: 2em;
}
```

or if you want certain classes of button to be a particular style you can use CSS classes:

```html
<input type="submit" id="search" value="Search" class="search" />
```

and

```css
input.search {
    width: 20em;  height: 2em;
}
```

I use ems as the measurement unit because they [tend to scale better](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=397663).

Comment: For Safari Mac, you'll also need to set `border: none` in order to see these changes.

Comment: ...and you can embed this in the html by enclosing it in `<style media="screen" type="text/css">...embed here...</style>` - wow!

Answer (score 71):

just use style attribute with height and width option

```
<input type="submit" id="search" value="Search"  style="height:50px; width:50px" />
```

Answer (score 11):

Change height using:

```css
input[type=submit] {
  border: none; /*rewriting standard style, it is necessary to be able to change the size*/
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<input type="button" value="submit" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; left: 250; top: 250;">
```

Use this with your requirements.

Answer (score 6):

You can change height and width with css:

```
#search {
     height: 100px;
     width: 400px;
}
```

It's worth pointing out that safari on OSX ignores most input button styles, however.

Comment: You might need to set `{border: none;}`

Answer (score 6):

Using [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/).

Either inside your `<head>` tag (the `#search` means "the element with an ID of `search`")

```
<style type="text/css">
    input#search
    {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

Or inline, in your `<input>` tag

```
<input type="submit" id="search" value="Search"  style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks I m using safari OSX and ive tred every answer and nothing alters it. What can I do?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried? There's no reason why any of these should fail :)

Comment: I have tried all the code posted in the question answers, is it my browser thats stopping it?

Comment: It shouldn't be, CSS has been a part of pretty much every browser for years now. The only thing that is at all likely is your implementation of the code. Without seeing the other code in the file that may affect it, we could give you a hundred things it could be, but each would be maybe a 1% chance of being correct.

Comment: For Safari Mac, you'll also need to set `border: none` in order to see these changes.

Answer (score 3):

Use the css `height` and `width` properties.

For this to work on Mac, you also need to set the `button`'s `border` to `none`.

Comment: Do you know why does it need to set border:none in mac?

Answer (score 1):

That's easy!
First, give your button an `id` such as `<input type="button" value="I am a button!" id="myButton" />`
Then, for height, and width, use CSS code:

```css
.myButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

You could also do this CSS:

```css
input[type="button"] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

But that would affect all the buttons on the Page.

Working example - [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vodn97j5/)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I tried all the above no good. So I just add a padding individually:

```css
 #button {

    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: crimson;
    border: 2px solid rgb(37, 34, 34);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Also a good point: by increasing font-size it automatically makes the button bigger! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add style="width:auto"

`<input type="submit" id="search" value="Search" style="width:auto" />`

This worked for me in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can change height and width using CSS:

```
#search{
     height:30px;
     width:100px;
}
```