# Iphone <button> image on form altered

Tags: html, iphone, forms, mobile

[image: Example]

Ok so here's my problem, i have 3 buttons that work on both pc and mobile phones, but 1 major difference, on mobile devices the button shrinks by 50% and magically gets round corners. (ignore the fact that the top image has a check and the bottom has a plus sign, they do the same exact thing)

```
<button type="button" onClick="parent.location='../index.php'" title="Back to Main Menu">
  <img src="../../css/images/back_25.png" />
</button>
<button type="reset" title="Reset">
  <img src="../../css/images/restart_25.png" />
</button>
<button type="submit" title="Done">
  <img src="../../css/images/plus_25.png" />
</button>
<input type="hidden" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

is there a quick fix to this problem? Once again both sets of buttons work properly, just look different.

As requested: i've also tried this code.

```
<button type="reset" style="width:49px; height:33px;">
<img src="../../css/images/restart_25.png" width="25" height="25" />
 </button>
```

it's the same thing. i've also tried to set to style="width:50px; height:50px, and the button becomes a full circle.

Comment: When you say mobile devices, which devices? How many have you tested?

Comment: only the iphone's safari so far. but that's really the only one i care about.

Comment: The images also look inflated. What if you give both the buttons and the images explicit sizes in pixels?

Comment: i've updated the question with your suggestion. 

also i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374001/how-to-edit-the-size-of-the-submit-button-on-a-form

you can see James near the bottom was having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, i really don't see anyone going to have an answer to my problem, so i just started messing with the height and width on the buttons a little more and got kinda of lucky to land on a middle ground on both browsers.

[image]

```
<button type="reset" title='Reset' style='height:33px; width:50px'>
   <img src="../../css/images/restart_25.png" />
</button>
```

This seemed to be the sweet spot for my specific situation. because the pc broswer side was not effected and the iphone/safari side is acceptable to see the icons.