# I'm unable to change the size of a button from a css page

Tags: html, css

I wanted to change the size of an input submit button on my web page. I used the methods presented on this page [How to edit the size of the submit button on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374001/how-to-edit-the-size-of-the-submit-button-on-a-form)

However except the method in which I change the size of the button directly in the html code on the line with input, I can't edit the size of the buttons. Here is my current code:

web page:

```css
p,h1,h2,label
{
 text-align: center;
}
body
{
 background-color: white;
 
}
#vote
{
 border: none;
 width: 100px;  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header> 
<h1> Site de vote </h1>
<h2> Télécommande de vote </h2>
</header>
<input type="submit" value="test" id="vote" class="vote" /> 

<form action="page_validation.php" method="post">
<p>
<input type="submit" name="reponse1" value="A" id="vote" class="vote"/>
<input type="submit" name="reponse2" value="B" id="vote" class="vote" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="reponse3" value="C" id="vote" class="vote"/>
<input type="submit" name="reponse4" value="D" id="vote" class="vote"/>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="reponse5" value="E" id="vote" class="vote" />
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="numero_question" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="user_name" id="theid" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="eval_number" id="myid" value="" />
</form>
```

I tried with the id (#vote) the class (input.vote) and I tried just input[type=submit] but none of these work. All the others changes applied in the css page (p,h1,...) work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I'm unable to replicate your problem, I copy and pasted your HTML and CSS inside a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PgdjGN) and it works.

The only thing I can think of is that your updated CSS is not being loaded within your browser. You can fix this by doing a forced refresh to clear your cache and use the latest version of your CSS file.

Press **CTRL + F5** to trigger a force refresh.

Hopefully this solves your problem.

***Side note!***

Be aware that an `id` is only allowed to exist once. Using an `id` multiple times has no effect on the functionality of your HTML, but it is not how your supposed to use an `id`. Also I **strongly** recommend that you don't use an `id` and a `class` with the *same* name on the *same* element.

So to have shared styling on your buttons you can just remove the `id="vote"`'s and replace them with `class="vote"`.

Comment: I changed the id and class names in order to conform to what you said in side note. However the main problem remains and I can't solve it even by triggering a force refresh. Thank you anyway

Comment: Ok I tried in another time and it worked finally I don't why it didn't work the first time but that's great.

Comment: @galgow Nice, happy to see that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that you have used id="vote" for many elements, you have to use each id just one time in the page, use specific id for each element and if you want to set style for manu element at the moment, you can use class that can be use for many elements

Comment: I removed the id for all the buttons and tried with a single one but it still doesn't work. The class doesn't work either to edit all the buttons